# SingleChildScrollView in Column Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The SingleChildScrollView is surrounded by the Flexible widget
because there's an overflow error. However, placing the Flexible
then makes the text too small!?

Please, how can I do this in a better way?

[image: multi-line text no visible]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //       primary: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: I10n.t('Playhouse'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
      ),
      endDrawer: const ScrapBookDrawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            /// Submodule Name |  Short Description
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.subTask['subName'],
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                      child: Text(
                        'Submodule description',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 5,
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  /// Large Picture
                  Crop(
                    interactive: false,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    dimColor: Colors.white,
                    controller: CropController(),
                    child: Image.memory(
                      base64.decode(
                        con.submodule['image'],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 200,

                    /// Rounded Container
                    child: Material(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 225,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                /// Task Name and Number
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 30, bottom: 20,),
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.subTask['name'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 26,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                /// Short Description or Title
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 10, bottom: 30,),
                                  child:
                                  Text(widget.subTask['short_description']),
                                ),
                                /// Long Description
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    child:
                                    Text(widget.subTask['long_description']),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the next version below, I've gotten rid of the Positioned widget, but now (marked with red arrows) I don't see how to get rid of the whitespace?

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: I10n.t('Playhouse'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
      ),
      endDrawer: const ScrapBookDrawer(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Crop(
            interactive: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            dimColor: Colors.white,
            controller: CropController(),
            child: Image.memory(
              base64.decode(
                con.submodule['image'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          widget.subTask['subName'],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Submodule description',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                const Spacer(),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        /// Task Name and Number
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 30,
                            bottom: 20,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.subTask['name'],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        /// Short Description or Title
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 10,
                            bottom: 30,
                          ),
                          child: Text(widget.subTask['short_description']),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        Flexible(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            child: Text(widget.subTask['long_description']),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that the second one is the closest to what you need, to remove the whitespace you only need to remove the bottom paddings and the sizedBox, because you are the one controlling the whitespaces with those widgets and set a width size to your container with long and short description, like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: I10n.t('Playhouse'),
    centerTitle: true,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    elevation: 0,
    excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
  ),
  endDrawer: const ScrapBookDrawer(),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Crop(
        interactive: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        dimColor: Colors.white,
        controller: CropController(),
        child: Image.memory(
          base64.decode(
            con.submodule['image'],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.subTask['subName'],
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      'Submodule description',
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
            const Spacer(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    color: Colors.white),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    /// Task Name and Number
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 30,
                        bottom: 20,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        widget.subTask['name'],
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 26,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    /// Short Description or Title
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10,
                      ),
                      child: Text(widget.subTask['short_description']),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        child: Text(widget.subTask['long_description']),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'll modify that portion of the screen.